# Лаконичное определение массива внутри скрипта

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно определить в скрипте массив целых чисел от 1 до 16 длиной 256 элементов. Как я делаю это сейчас?

Вот так.

```
var cells = '0123456789abcdef...'.split('');
```

Строка длинная. :(

Массивов таких несколько, нечитаемый код получается. Как бы его сократить?

Массивы используются в решателе для 16-ти клеточного Судоку. Решатель содержит функцию, которая определяет, какую очередную цифру можно поставить в клетку. Ниже приведет код (для краткости для 4-х клеточного Судоку):

```
function GetNextValidGiven(givens, given, index) {
    // Это строки
    var r = '0000111122223333'.split('');
    // Это столбцы
    var c = '0123012301230123'.split('');
    // Это блоки
    var b = '0011001122332233'.split('');

    var allowed = ' 123';

    // Пройти всю таблицу, развернутую в строку
    // Для каждой ячейки определить, нет одинаковых цифр в строке, столбце и блоке
    for (var i = 0; i < givens.length; i++) {
        if (givens[i] != ' ' && allowed.indexOf(givens[i]) != -1) {
            if (r[i] == r[index] || c[i] == c[index] || b[i] == b[index]) {
                allowed = allowed.replace(givens[i], '');
            }
        }
    }

    return allowed[allowed.indexOf(given) + 1];
}
```

Comment: Для каких целей нужен массив? Может тогда будет проще ответить на твой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function genStr(length)
{
    var str = "0123456789abcdef", ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        ret += str.charAt(i%str.length);
    }
    return ret;
}
alert(genStr(256));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вынес все массивы (если еще где-то есть такие же) в отдельный скрипт, где были бы только данные. Можно даже отказаться от кодирования строкой и инициализировать сразу через JSON.